# FirebaseError: Missing routing header. Please fill in the request header with format x-goog-request-params:project_id=example-2&database_id=test

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

Firestore named database on angular fire 7.5.0

Angular fire configuration on app.module.ts

```
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore('test')), //use named firestore database
```

reading the collection works correctly

```
 private firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);
  private collectionName = environment.firestoreCollections.example;
 const c = collection(this.firestore, this.collectionName);
      const q = query(c, orderBy('name'));
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

      const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(item => {
        return { ...item.data(), id: item.id }
      }) as Example[];

      return data;
```

but on counting documents with aggregation queries return error

```
 private firestore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);
  private collectionName = environment.firestoreCollections.example;
const c = collection(this.firestore, this.collectionName);
      const snapshot = await getCountFromServer(c);
      return snapshot.data().count;
```

```
[
    {
        "error": {
            "code": 400,
            "message": "Missing routing header. Please fill in the request header with format x-goog-request-params:project_id=example-2&database_id=test. Please refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-databases#access_a_named_database_with_a_client_library for more details.",
            "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
        }
    }
]
```

any idea of integrate angular fire with named firestore database or about of this error? when i use (default) firestore database works correctly with aggregation queries

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this error occurs when you are not using the latest version of the firebase client sdk.

I had the same issue using vue. Updating the firebase SDK from 9.23.0 to 10.6.0 resolved the issue.

Please be aware that an update to another major version might be a breaking change for your code.